# Python Sqlite3 Update query not working

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to compare the prices of some products stored on my database, while the comparison works fine, the update statement doesn't seem to update the desired field.

```
for currentRow,newRow in zip(currentInfo,newInfo):

    if currentRow[1]!=newRow[1]:
        print(currentRow[0],newRow[0])
        print("The price of %s has changed from %s to %s" %    (currentRow[0], currentRow[1], newRow[1]))
        db.execute("update table set Prices=? where Product=?",(newRow[1],currentRow[0]))
        conn.commit
```

Comment: commit is a method `conn.commit()`

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf I'm really embarrassed...I forgot to add the parenthesis. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just missed the ().

`conn.commit()`

Comment: Thanks - helped me too. The fact it doesn't give any error message is confusing.